# Gradle systemProperty in custom task not setting Spring Profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-profiles, gradle-task

I'm trying to selectively deactive tests if there is a spring profile called "unit", which is working:

```java
@DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable(named = "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", matches = "unit")
```

If I run `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=unit ./gradlew clean test` this works fine. The issue I'm having is that I don't want to have to write all that out, and instead I want a custom gradle task, also called "unit". It currently looks like this:

```java
task unit(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "unit"
}
```

This runs all tests, even if they are supposed to be disabled. I tried `useJUnitPlatform { sysProp... }`, I tried adding `options { sysProp... }`, I tried using `doFirst`, I tried switching `"SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE"` to `"spring.profiles.active"` in both the build.gradle and in the annotation, I tried `systemProperties "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE": "unit"` but that doesn't work.

I found lots of StackOverflow questions where people just put systemProperties into the default test task, but I couldn't find anything with a custom task.

**What do I need to call where to get the task to pass a spring profile system property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable` annotation requires environment variable to be set. Try to set environment variable instead of system property in Your task:

```
task unit(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    environment "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "unit"
}
```